# How to create a contribution or event report that indicates amount of payment and balance owed

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civireport

We run CiviCRM 4.7.21. In events, we are able to indicate a registration payment toward the total with the balance owed within each participant's registration page. However, we have not been able to determine how to run a report that indicates partial payment and balance owed. Is there an event or contribution report that can be configured to run a report that shows both the partial payment amount and the balance owed?

Answer (score 3):

In the event participant report there is the option to add columns for total paid & balance.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to civicrm stackexchange. I can't answer your question specifically as a quick search for a report that does this didn't turn anything up.

The wiki page for partial payments is [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Partial+Payments+for+Event+Registrations+and+Memberships) but i don't see anything specifically indicating new reports were created for it but rather that

> Existing search and report filters allow users to filter on Participant and Membership status, and therefore can be used as-is to locate partially paid records. Reports which calculate revenue based on completed contribution summation should continue to provide accurate revenue totals.

There are a couple of additional report solutions that may be worth investigating but I suspect neither have yet accommodated the 'partial payment' issue (which I haven't seen in use personally). The two I am thinking of are

- [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)
- [Line Item Report](https://civicrm.org/blog/jproffitt/announcing-the-line-item-report-extension)