# event income reports

Tags: civireport

I'm not getting the results that I expect from the event income reports. I've used the "No-show" status for people who have paid but don't turn up to the event. However the report only seems to included the income for participants with a status that is "Counted". That's right for the attendee numbers, but not for the finance. If I set the "No-Show" status to be "Counted" then I assume the figures will come right, but it won't show the numbers actually at the event. I can't think of a way round this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is simply not covered. You can read more related threads on SE question [How to create a contribution or event report that indicates amount of payment and balance owed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/how-to-create-a-contribution-or-event-report-that-indicates-amount-of-payment-an) and at the old forum on [Event Income Report Misleading - need to look at actual contributions, not fees](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=11955.0.html).

How can we get reports with real event payment status and no expected incomes? This is a very common request from our users that we have yet to respond.